# XNA Content Loading

Tags: xna

Anybody know how i can stream load Model data in XNA 4 Content Loader ?

And not have to specify a farken filename ...
Was hoping somehow get a stream running as the model data resides on a db.
And no, im not interested in temp files :p

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the Content Pipeline for this, you can subclass `ContentManager` and override `OpenStream`. This would assume that the built XNB files reside in the database and you can provide the stream to them when requested :)

Answer (score 0):

`Content.Load<Model>()` requires a `string` parameter, so I don't think that you'll be able to stream a `Model` in.  I should mention that the `string` parameter that is required is a `filePath`, so you wouldn't be able to convert a `stream` to a `string` and pass that in.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should help. If I remember correctly, I can't check because I'm at work, it lets you run the content importer on a stream dynamically. So you should be able to dump your file in a MemeoryStream and load it so long as its any of the file types XNA supports.

Be warned though this is pretty slow because you have to compile every file when you load it.

Curious of why you need to load from a database. I assume its from a remote server? In which case the download time + compile time might be a bit much. since it sounds like you would have to do it every time the game is loaded.

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2